# How can I get a value into a registry entry (via batch) that contains %1?

Tags: batch-file, regedit

I am running a batch file with the following content:

```
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\abc\command" /d "hello %1 wow"
```

In the registry entry ("Standard") only "hello wow" appears, but not the %1 in the middle. But I need that for my requirement. Does anyone know how I get it in there as value?

Comment: Please open a Command Prompt window, type `reg add /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the usage information for the command you are currently using incorrectly, to find out what is incorrect about what you've posted. What you need is a registry value, `/V`. As for your reported issue, in order to not expand a `%` character when using a batch file, you need to escape it with another `%` character, i.e. `%%1`, you should also change it to remove any possible surrounding doublequotes, i.e. `"hello %%~1 wow"`

Comment: I would also strongly advise that you do not create a registry entry for every user who ever uses that PC. You should create it only for you, which means under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. For example `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe "HKCU\Software\Classes\*\shell\abc\command" /VE /D "hello %%~1 wow"`. The same of course would be true of the other key which should be created along side this, which should carry the name, you''re wanting to see in the context menu too

Answer (score 0):

Probably (I haven't tried this)

```
reg add "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\abc\command" /d "hello %%1 wow"
```

`%` is a special character in batch. Other special characters like `&|` and others need to be "escaped" by being preceded by `^` (although sometimes by `\` - depending on the utility) but the escape character for `%` is `%` itself.

Comment: You should really add the missing value, e.g. (Default): `%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe "HKCR\*\shell\abc\command" /VE /D "hello %%1 wow"`.